# Solidity source code filename extension

Tags: solidity, ide

I'm just starting coding in solidarity. I want my syntax highlighter [Vim Solidity](https://github.com/tomlion/vim-solidity/) to make my code look pretty.

What filename extension should I use for my source code?

For example, Javascript uses `.js`.

What does Solidity use?

Comment: yes, you should use `filename.sol` extension for solidity files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `filename.sol`

The wiki page on the [command line compiler](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html) says to use `.sol` as the file name extension.